# String operations in R

Tags: arrays, r, string

Suppose I have a string in this format in R:

```
"A<2 & A<=3 & B>5 & B<=1 & A<1"
```

Now I hope to get the four variables i.e. '**A_less**'(A<) , '**A_greater**'(A>) , '**B_less'**(B<) and '**B_greate**r'(B>) that contatin their respective values i.e.

in case of 'A<' compare all values for that particular substring and give the best value for that condition i.e

```
'A_less' = 1
'B_less' = 1
'B_greater' = 5
'A_greater' = NA
```

another example:

```
string <- c("A>3 & A<9 & A<=-1 & A>2 & B<=5")
```

then the output of the variable would be

```
'A_less' = -1
'A_greater' = 3
'B_less' = 5
'B_greater' = NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and where do you have problems? Have you thought of the algorithm which would produce this result?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
library(stringr)
get_min_max=function(x)
{
  A_less=min(as.numeric(str_match_all(x,'(?:A<=?)(-?[0-9|\\.]+)')[[1]][,2]))
  B_less=min(as.numeric(str_match_all(x,'(?:B<=?)([-?0-9|\\.]+)')[[1]][,2]))
  A_greater=max(as.numeric(str_match_all(x,'(?:A>=?)(-?[0-9|\\.]+)')[[1]][,2]))
  B_greater=max(as.numeric(str_match_all(x,'(?:B>=?)(-?[0-9|\\.]+)')[[1]][,2]))
  A_less=ifelse(A_less==-Inf,NA,A_less)
  B_less=ifelse(A_less==-Inf,NA,B_less)
  A_greater=ifelse(A_greater==-Inf,NA,A_greater)
  B_greater=ifelse(B_greater==-Inf,NA,B_greater)
  return(c(A_less,B_less,A_greater,B_greater))
}
```

Edit: Created a function. Now takes cares of decimals as per as the comment

Comment: These commands are rounding off the values. Please tell me how to avoid it. e.g. if min(A) is 1.2, it shows A_less = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for `stringr` and extract the different parts like so:

```
library("stringr")
string <- c("A>3 & A<9 & A<=-1 & A>2 & B<=5")
str_match_all(string, "([A-Z])([<>=]+)(\\d)")
```

Which yields:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]   [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A>3"  "A"  ">"  "3" 
[2,] "A<9"  "A"  "<"  "9" 
[3,] "A>2"  "A"  ">"  "2" 
[4,] "B<=5" "B"  "<=" "5"
```

Loop over the result and apply some if/else constructs afterwards.